# How to scale non-built-in/custom fonts in wpf C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am currently trying to make a program that has a kind of launch screen before kicking into the actual program itself. I've decided to use wpf for the program, therefore, the launch screen must be written in XAML. I kind of got the knack of it, but I ran into a problem while trying to scale a font that I downloaded off the internet. It seems as if the scaling only works for built-in and/or system fonts. Is there a way I would be able to scale it anyways? Every time I try the method of putting it inside a viewbox it just scales everything down. I tried replacing all the text with Calibri to see if it would fix it, and sure enough it did. However, to be clear, I do NOT want to use Calibri or any other built-in font, unless it is really "clean". For anyone wondering, the font is called Gidole. Thanks. Here is the XAML code:

```
<Window x:Name="StartPage" x:Class="ModernBoard.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ModernBoard"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="ModernBoard Welcome Page" ShowInTaskbar="False" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Background="#FF191919" Foreground="#FFE6E6E6" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" FontFamily="Gidole" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Height="260.301" Width="653.627" FontStretch="Expanded">
    <Viewbox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="231" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="648" Stretch="None">
        <Grid>
            <Label x:Name="WelcomeTo" Content="Welcome to" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="38,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="82" Height="27" FontFamily="Gidole" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FFE6E6E6"/>
            <Label x:Name="Modern" Content="Modern" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="37,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="356" Height="120"  FontSize="90" Foreground="#FFE6E6E6" FontFamily="Gidole" FontWeight="Thin"/>
            <Label x:Name="Board" Content="Board" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="336,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="265" Height="120"  FontSize="90" Foreground="#FFE6E6E6" FontFamily="Gidole" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Button x:Name="New" Content="New Board" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="44,135,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="272" FontWeight="DemiBold" Foreground="#FFE6E6E6" Background="#2c406e" BorderThickness="0" Height="24"/>
            <Button x:Name="Open" Content="Open Board" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="329,135,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="272" FontWeight="DemiBold" Foreground="#FFE6E6E6" Background="#2c406e" BorderThickness="0" Height="24"/>
            <Button x:Name="Import" Content="Import File" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="44,168,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="557" FontWeight="DemiBold" Foreground="#FFE6E6E6" Background="#2c406e" BorderThickness="0" Height="24"/>
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
</Window>
```

Here is a screenshot of the preview: [Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqiJd.png)

Here is what the program looks like, while running: [Running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLBQa.png)

Thanks in advance,

Alex Fanat

Answer (score 0):

You can 'scale' the font by simply specifying a FontSize attribute on the 'Welcome To' label. You may also want to consider removing the Width/Height attributes otherwise you'll see the label text cropped.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it still did not work. I think you are misunderstanding the question; I would like the actual program to look like it does in the preview, which it currently does not. When I run the program both labels are scaled down, and the font weights are not displaying properly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being with the way I installed the font; it was installed but not loaded properly. I managed to fix it though.